# caller 0 gives wrong line number in trap handler

Tags: bash, shell

When using the caller builtin in a Bash trap function, the result of `caller 0` gives the wrong line number, always giving `1`. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
function foo {
    exit 1
}
function bar {
    foo
}
function err {
    (( i = 0 ))
    while caller $i; do
        (( ++i ))
    done
}
trap err EXIT
bar
```

gives the following output:

```
1 foo ./test.sh
6 bar ./test.sh
15 main ./test.sh
```

While the output for `i > 0` is correct, when using `caller 0` in a trap handler it always seems to give `1` as the line number. Is there any way to get the real line number of the failed function from a trap handler?

Comment: The `BASH_LINENO` array is your friend. (So are `FUNCNAME` and `BASH_SOURCE`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Unfortunately `BASH_LINENO` just gives the same thing as `caller 0`: `1`

Comment: ...and so does `trap 'err "$LINENO"'`, for that matter. Frankly, I've never seen EXIT traps used this way -- you're probably hitting behavior nobody ever bothered to test. Using an ERR trap would be much less unusual.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Trapping on ERR works even less well than trapping on EXIT: I can only get the first caller (but at least with the right line number!). I trap on EXIT because in my real scripts I use `set -e` to exit on error.

Comment: ...well, damn. I've done this before, but for a codebase locked inside a former employer, and on investigation it turns out to be a bit trickier than I remember.

Comment: Could be a regression. `bash` 4.1 and 4.3 shows your output, while `bash` 3.2 shows `3 foo ./test.sh`.

Comment: I looked at `FUNCNAME`, `BASH_LINENO`, and `BASH_SOURCE` recently, because I wanted to implement them in mksh. I think the implementation is buggy and does not behave according to the manpage, because, from my reading of it, these three arrays must not all three have the same length (I think `BASH_SOURCE` must be one longer than the other two).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug introduced sometime after 3.2.57(1)-release:

```
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

$ bash ./test.sh
3 foo ./test.sh
6 bar ./test.sh
15 main ./test.sh

$ /usr/local/bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ /usr/local/bin/bash ./test.sh
1 foo ./test.sh
6 bar ./test.sh
15 main ./test.sh
```

There seems to already be a [bug report](http://savannah.gnu.org/support/?108750) with the bash project.

Comment: The [bugs in ERR and RETURN traps are fixed now](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2015-02/msg00132.html)

Comment: This seems to have been fixed, at least in my testing.

Comment: I'm using bash 5.0.17, and this problem appears to have returned.